# Changing Android Studio's toolbar icons to larger ones and adding labels

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

[image]

I'd like to make the IDE's toolbar icons larger and add labels..

Is there some way to do this? I've tried Google but it is returning results for toolbars on Android devices, not Android Studio. I also tried looking at IntelliJ resources but no luck there either.

Comment: Is your question about the IDE or the Android `Toolbar` icon?

Comment: The IDE. I have updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: It's still not clear what icons you are referring to. Screenshots could help

Comment: Ah, those. Yeah... I just know the keyboard shortcuts and hardly ever click the toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to say you can't make them larger...

> [**Configuring Menus and Toolbars**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-menus-and-toolbars.html)
>
> *The size of the toolbar icons should be 16x16*

Answer (score 0):

### 2022 UPDATE

This info ([hinted at on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763698/how-to-change-the-toolbar-and-icons-scale-in-intellij-idea)) is from [jetbrains support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007994999) for IntelliJ. It may also apply to Android Studio. Scaling of UI elements is controlled by two factors:

1. HiDPI mode:

   a. JRE-managed: `Help | Edit Custom VM Options` set `-Dsun.java2d.uiScale.enabled=true`

   b. IDE-mananaged: set with `Dsun.java2d.uiScale.enabled=false`
2. Scale Factor:

   a. User scale factor: default setting is based on the font size in `Settings > Appearance and Behavior > Appearance > Use custom font`. Increase it by setting scale > 1.0 with this VM option: `-Dide.ui.scale=1.25`.

   b. System scale factor: default is base on OS; override with this VM option: `-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.75`.

To see your current settings: `Help | Find Action:` and type `Show HiDPI Info`.

Comment: Using the jetbrains system-scale setting `-Dide.ui.scale=2.0` did the trick on 2021.2.1