# How to change the toolbar and icons scale in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

It seems to me that in my IDE everything is too petty. I would like there to be a font about the same as inside the editor. How can I do it?

[image]

And how can I increase the scale of the launch icons? Although I see everything perfectly, it seems inconvenient for me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA user interface/icons are scaled automatically depending on the system DPI/scaling settings.

You can try to override it in Help | Edit Custom VM Options (effective after IDE restart):

```
-Dide.ui.scale=1.5
```

Menu/toolbar font/size can be overridden in the IDE Appearance settings:

[image: font]

More details can be found in [this document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007994999).

Comment: NOTE: each VM argument needs to be on its own line, otherwise IDEA won't boot. I had to manually find/edit `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2022.1\idea64.exe.vmoptions` afterwards to fix.